# how to merge data from different array to a combined array in json form

Tags: javascript, arrays

how to merge data from different array to a combined array in json form.

```
 let NAME: any[] =[]
  let TYPE: any[] = []
  let OBJ: any[] =[]


  for (var i=0;i<getdata.length;i++)
  {
    var p =getdata[i].name;    
    **var a =NAME.push(p);**     // pushing data to Name

    for (var j in getTypes[i])
    {
    if (getdata[i].name ==getTypes[i][j].data.name) // get type is having req. data here
      {

        var k = getTypes[i][j].name ;
        **var s =TYPE.push(k);** //pushing data to type

      }
    }
      for (var j in getobj[i])
    {
      if (getdata[i].name ==getobj[i][j].library.name)         
      {
        var o = getobj[i][j].name ;
        **var g = OBJ.push(o);** // pushing data to OBJ
      }
    }
  }     
 
  console.log(NAME);   // result getting :- ['A','B','C']
  console.log(TYPE);    // result getting :- ['A1','A2','B1','B2','C1','C2']
  console.log(OBJ);   // result getting :- ['AA1','AA2','BB1','BB2','CC1','CC2']
});
```

Data required like this :

{
id=1;
NAME: A
OBJ:'A1','A2'
TYPE:'AA1','AA2'
}

{
id=2;
NAME: B
OBJ:'B1','B2'
TYPE:'BB1','BB2'
}

{
id=C;
NAME: C
OBJ:'C1','C2'
TYPE:'CC1','CC2'
}

Comment: Please add the structure of `getdata`, `getTypes`, `getobj` - as it will be helpful to improve understanding.

Comment: The desired output is also not clear. Do you need the data to look like this: `[{ id: 1, NAME: 'A', OBJ: ['A1', 'A2'], TYPE: ['AA1', 'AA2']}, { id: 2, NAME: 'B', OBJ: ['B1', 'B2'], TYPE: ['BB1', 'BB2']}, { id: 3, NAME: 'C', OBJ: ['C1', 'C2'], TYPE: ['CC1', 'CC2']}]` ? ie, array of objects where each object has 'id', 'NAME', 'OBJ', 'TYPE' props where 'OBJ' and 'TYPE' have values which are string-array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const NAME = ['A','B','C']
const OBJ = ['A1','A2','B1','B2','C1','C2']
const TYPE = ['AA1','AA2','BB1','BB2','CC1','CC2']

const result = []
NAME.forEach((item, index) => {
  const obj = []
  const type = []
  obj.push(obj[index], obj[index + 1])
  type.push(type[index], type[index+1])
  result.push({
    id: index + 1,
    NAME: item,
    OBJ: obj,
    TYPE: type
  })
})

return result
```